# Jenkins fresh installation does not start on Fedora 25

Tags: java, jenkins, fedora-25

I have installed Jenkins on Fedora 25 using dnf. However, when I access the default URL I see 503 exception.

Is this behaviour seen by the others? Do we need to change any configuration after the installation or are there any dependencies?

Jenkins logs show the following error

```
Feb 01, 2017 6:34:01 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context w.{,file:/usr/share/jenkins/webroot/},/usr/share/jenkins/webroot
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/jenkins/webroot/WEB-INF/lib/mina-core.jar (Too many levels of symbolic links)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.matched(JarScanner.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.matchPatterns(PatternMatcher.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.match(PatternMatcher.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.scan(JarScanner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:457)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration$1.preConfigure(HostConfiguration.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:152)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:290)
    at Main.main(Main.java:104)
```

Comment: You get a file not found due to `(Too many levels of symbolic links)` sounds like there are some link loops. Maybe the package is broken, or dnf does something strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer finally! hope this helps for others as well

```
cd /usr/share/jenkins/webroot/WEB-INF/lib
sudo ln -sf `build-classpath jtidy` jtidy.jar
sudo ln -sf `build-classpath apache-mina/mina-core` mina-core.jar

sudo systemctl start jenkins.service
```

Thanks Tim Way
[Open Bug 1401161](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1401161)

Thanks Redlab for looking into this :)

Hopefully this will get fixed soon!